# About saving MSER regions plotted on an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a large number of images and I am computing their MSER regions using MATLAB 20143a. and trying to save them plotted on the image (basically a visualisation of computed MSER regions). I do that as follows (a snippet of the code !!) :

```
for i =1  : length(files)
    img = imread(files{i});
    regions = detectMSERRegions(img);
    figure('Visible','Off');
    imshow(img,[]);
    hold on;
    plot(regions);
    saveas(gcf,fullfile(save_path,files{i}));
 end
```

Though this gets my job done, i have seen that it takes a lot of time (which I find unreasonable. Is there a better (supposedly a faster mechanism to save these plots ?) I have a number of such files and the resolution is 576 by 720 which does not seem to be a too large a resolution for MATLAB.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you run the debugger to check how much time was also taken by calls to `imshow` and `plot` vs those to `saveas`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use GETFRAME and IMWRITE instead of SAVEAS

```
regions = detectMSERFeatures(image);
figure('Visible','Off');
imshow(image,[]);
hold on;
plot(image);
F = getframe(gca); % Not the GCF
imwrite(F.cdata, 'image.jpg');
```

it should be faster

Comment: I am sorry but that does not help. Though it does the work, but even after setting visible property off, it keeps on showing the image at getframe and hangs in there, waiting for some sort of keyboard action.

Comment: I've changed the `regions = detectMSERFeatures(image);` to `[mserRegions, mserConnComp] = detectMSERFeatures(rgb2gray(img), ...
'RegionAreaRange',[200 8000],'ThresholdDelta',4);` and `plot(image);` to `plot(mserRegions, 'showPixelList', true,'showEllipses',false);` and its working very good. thank you!